# Providing default value of cin input

Tags: c++, cin

My app reads user input using `std::cin` stream.
In one place I would like to provide default input and let the user to accept it as it is (by pressing enter) or modify it before continuing (by removing old characters with backspace and adding new text).

I'm aware that characters can be placed directly into `cin.rdbuf`, but that's not exactly what I want to achieve.
I would like to put characters into console window in the place where console's cursor is when waiting for user input and do no read them before user will accept them. User should be also able to remove them and write their own text.

Can something like this be achieve using `cin` or do I have to simulate this by reading single characters and repainting content of the console?

Comment: If you want to have something like pre-filled screen masks rather lookup [ncurses](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html).

Comment: You'll need some sort of console library to do this eg [Microsoft's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for Windows, or [libreadline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, something like that cannot be done with `std::cin`. Its read buffer is read directly from standard input. Standard input is a "cooked" character stream. All the editing is handled entirely by your operating system's terminal console, and pressing `Enter` results in your application's `std::cin` reading the entered text.

The traditional way this is done is to simply indicate the default input value in the prompt itself, and use the default value in the event of empty input, something like:

```
std::string buffer;

std::cout << "What color is the sky [blue]? ";

std::getline(std::cin, buffer);

if (buffer.size() == 0)
      buffer="blue";
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. However your example won't work in my case, because my goal is to prevent user from coercion of writing whole text, when they want to modify it only a little. For example: [default]: _someReallyLongName1_ [user input]: _someReallyLongName2_